# Magento 2 Order collection filter by product set id

Tags: magento2, orders, attribute-set

In Magento 2, I need to get order collection filter by date range and product set id.
I tried [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/329620/35778) way, not worked.

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 0):

Please used below code or prefer this [Resource Link](https://www.technicalmrstar.com/how-to-filter-magento-2-order-collection-by-date-range-and-product-set-id/)

**Step 1**: Setting Up the Script

```
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/../app/bootstrap.php';

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$areaCode = Area::AREA_ADMINHTML;

try {
    $objectManager->get(\Magento\Framework\App\State::class)->setAreaCode($areaCode);
} catch (LocalizedException $e) {
    // Area code is already set
}

$dateTime = $objectManager->get(DateTime::class);
$collectionFactory = $objectManager->get(CollectionFactory::class);

// Set your product set ID
$productSetId = 4;

try {
    
    $orderCollection = $collectionFactory->create();
    $orderCollection->addFieldToFilter(
        'created_at',
        [
            'from' => $dateTime->gmtDate('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('2022-01-01')),
            'to' => $dateTime->gmtDate('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('2023-01-01')),
            'date' => true
        ]
    );

    $orderIds = [];

    foreach ($orderCollection as $order) {

        $orderItems = $order->getAllVisibleItems();
        $orderContainsProductSet = false;

        foreach ($orderItems as $item) {
            $product = $item->getProduct();

            if ($product !== null) {
                $itemProductSetId = $product->getAttributeSetId();
                if ($itemProductSetId == $productSetId) {
                    $orderContainsProductSet = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if ($orderContainsProductSet) {
            $orderIds[] = $order->getId();
        }
    }

    foreach ($orderIds as $orderId) {
        echo "Order ID: " . $orderId . "\n";
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

**Remember to adapt the script to your specific requirements and use it responsibly to maintain the integrity of your e-commerce data.**

[Resource Link](https://www.technicalmrstar.com/how-to-filter-magento-2-order-collection-by-date-range-and-product-set-id/)

**I hope this is helpful to you!!**

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code if works for you.

```
$collection = $this->_orderCollectionFactory->create()->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$collection->getSelect()
    ->join(array('order_item' => 'sales_order_item'),'main_table.entity_id = order_item.order_id')
    ->where("order_item.product_id IN (?)", ['123', '234', '456']);
```

**Thanks**

Answer (score 0):

```
$startDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('2023-04-01')); // Start range
$endDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('2023-10-01')); // End range

//the order collection
$orders = $this->orderCollectionFactory->create();

// Add filter orders by the specified date range
$orders->addFieldToFilter('created_at', ['from' => $startDate, 'to' => $endDate]);

// Join with order items table
$orders->join(
    ['order_item' => $orders->getTable('sales_order_item')],
    'main_table.entity_id = order_item.order_id',
    ['product_id']
);

//single product id filter
$product_id = 11141;
$orders->addFieldToFilter('order_item.product_id', ['eq' => $product_id]); //If specific product id

//multiple product ids filter
$productIds = array(4414,1115,225,678,990,500);
$orders->addFieldToFilter('order_item.product_id', ['in' => $productIds]); //If specifc product ids


//uncomment below and comment above product id filter lines if product id range
/* 
$productIdStartRange = 1101;
$productIdEndRange = 3305;
$orders->addFieldToFilter('order_item.product_id', array('gteq'=>$productIdStartRange));
$orders->addFieldToFilter('order_item.product_id', array('lteq'=>$productIdEndRange));
*/

if($orders->getSize() > 0){
    foreach ($orders as $order) {
        // your logic here
    }
}
```